# How do I get information out of my entry box to use later in my program in Python?

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

How can get information from my entry point? I'd like to be able to look at my matrix and pick certain input entries from my loop to see what is in the entry box. Here is my code so far:

```
rows = int(input('How many rows does your matrix have?: '))
cols = int(input('How many columns does your matrix have?: '))
win = GraphWin('Matrix', 300,300)
win.setBackground('white')
total = 1
for i in range(rows):
    y = 75 + 40*i
    for k in range(cols):
        x = 50 + 50*k
        entry = Entry(Point(x,y),3)
        entry.draw(win)
        k
print(entry.getText())
```

Comment: ignore 'total' that was for something I had tried earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are reusing your `entry` variable so the only `Entry` you have a pointer to is the *last* one.  We need to keep a `list` of `Entry` instances so we can poll them:

```
from graphics import *

rows = int(input('How many rows does your matrix have?: '))
cols = int(input('How many columns does your matrix have?: '))

win = GraphWin('Matrix', cols * 60, rows * 60)

entries = []

for i in range(rows):
    y = 75 + i*40
    for k in range(cols):
        x = (k + 1) * 50
        entry = Entry(Point(x, y), 3)
        entry.draw(win)

        entries.append(entry)

win.getMouse()
win.close()

for entry in entries:
    print(entry.getText())
```

Once the interface comes up, click on `Entry` boxes and enter letters -- don't click elsewhere.  When you're done, click on the background of the window and the interface should go away and print the contents of all the `Entry` boxes to the console.  Rework as your needs demand.